# Ruby: the closest date to specific date

Tags: arrays, ruby, date

I have a problem with my ruby script. I have an array

```
files = ["2020-09-14.access","2020-09-13.access","2020-09-11.access","2020-09-10.access","2020-09-09.access","2020-09-08.access","2020-09-07.access","2020-09-05.access","2020-09-04.access","2020-09-02.access","2020-09-01.access","2020-09-14.sale","2020-09-12.sale","2020-09-08.sale","2020-09-07.sale","2020-09-06.sale","2020-09-04.sale",]
```

that contains values that are file names. There are two types of files: access and sale. Every file name contains date of file creating. From each file type I want to get only these values with older dates beginning form file created two days ago. For the file type sale there is no problem, today is `2020-09-14`, file created two days ago is `2020-09-12.sale`. But in case access files there is no file created `2020-09-12` so I want file with the closest date to `2020-09-12` which means value `2020-09-10.access` and I'm stack in here. In short I want to get array like this

```
to_del_files = [["2020-09-10.access","2020-09-09.access","2020-09-08.access","2020-09-07.access","2020-09-05.access","2020-09-04.access","2020-09-02.access","2020-09-01.access"],["2020-09-12.sale","2020-09-08.sale","2020-09-07.sale","2020-09-06.sale","2020-09-04.sale"]]
```

My code is below:

```
require 'date'
files = ["2020-09-14.access","2020-09-13.access","2020-09-10.access","2020-09-09.access","2020-09-08.access","2020-09-07.access","2020-09-05.access","2020-09-04.access","2020-09-02.access","2020-09-01.access","2020-09-14.sale","2020-09-12.sale","2020-09-08.sale","2020-09-07.sale","2020-09-06.sale","2020-09-04.sale",]

names = files.map {|x| x.split('.')[1] }.uniq
puts names
date = Date.today
date2ago = date -2
to_del_files = []
names.each do |item|
    tmp = files.select { |x| x =~ /#{item}/ }
    flag = tmp.select {|x| x =~ /#{date2ago}/ }
    if flag.size > 0
        index = tmp.find_index("#{flag[0]}")
        to_del_files << tmp[index..-1]
    else
        #what to do in case where there is no such date in files
    end
end
puts to_del_files
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: With no Rails tag the assumption is that you want a pure-Ruby solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for you to get the files to delete:

```
def old_files(files, date)
  files.sort.filter { |file| Date.parse(file) < date }
end
```

And then you can use:

```
files = ["2020-09-14.access","2020-09-13.access","2020-09-10.access","2020-09-09.access","2020-09-08.access","2020-09-07.access","2020-09-05.access","2020-09-04.access","2020-09-02.access","2020-09-01.access","2020-09-14.sale","2020-09-12.sale","2020-09-08.sale","2020-09-07.sale","2020-09-06.sale","2020-09-04.sale",]

today = Date.today
date = today -2

to_del_files = old_files(files, date)
```

Comment: This requires Rails or at least ActiveSupport to work

Comment: I changed this code a little
def old_files(files, date)
  files.sort { |a, b| a <=> b }.filter { |file| Date.parse(file) < date }
end
date_t = Date.today
date = date_t -1

to_del_files = old_files(files, date)
and works very well :)

Comment: I suggest you use `Date::strptime` instead of  `Date.parse`, as the latter can return unexpected results. For example, `Date.parse("But maybe Bob was the murderer after all") #=> #<Date: 2020-05-01 ((2458971j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>`.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you wish to select elements from `files` corresponding to dates that are equal to or earlier than a given date. If that is correct you can do that as follows.

```
files = [
  "2020-09-14.access", "2020-09-13.access", "2020-09-11.access",
  "2020-09-10.access", "2020-09-09.access", "2020-09-08.access",
  "2020-09-07.access", "2020-09-05.access", "2020-09-04.access",
  "2020-09-02.access", "2020-09-01.access", "2020-09-14.sale",
  "2020-09-12.sale",   "2020-09-08.sale",   "2020-09-07.sale",
  "2020-09-06.sale",   "2020-09-04.sale"
]
```

```
require 'date'

def files_on_or_before_date(arr)
  files_on_or_before_target_date(arr, Date.now-2)
end

def files_on_or_before_target_date(arr, target_date)
  arr.select { |d| Date.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%d') <= target_date }
end
```

```
files_on_or_before_target_date(files, Date.new(2020, 9, 12))
  #=> ["2020-09-11.access", "2020-09-10.access", "2020-09-09.access",
  #    "2020-09-08.access", "2020-09-07.access", "2020-09-05.access",
  #    "2020-09-04.access", "2020-09-02.access", "2020-09-01.access",
  #    "2020-09-12.sale",   "2020-09-08.sale",   "2020-09-07.sale",
  #    "2020-09-06.sale",   "2020-09-04.sale"]
```

```
files_on_or_before_target_date(files, Date.new(2020, 9, 10))
  #=> ["2020-09-10.access", "2020-09-09.access", "2020-09-08.access",
  #    "2020-09-07.access", "2020-09-05.access", "2020-09-04.access",
  #    "2020-09-02.access", "2020-09-01.access", "2020-09-08.sale",
  #    "2020-09-07.sale",   "2020-09-06.sale",   "2020-09-04.sale"]
```

These return values can of course be added to an array.

See [Date::strptime](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime) and [DateTime#strftime](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-strftime), the latter for date formatting directives.

```
Date.strptime("2020-09-14.access", '%Y-%m-%d')
```

returns the same `Date` object as does

```
Date.strptime("2020-09-14", '%Y-%m-%d')
```

To guard against possible future change in the implementation of `Date::strptime` `strptime`'s argument `d` could be replaced with `d[/[^.]+/]` or `d[0, d.index('.')]`, both of which become `"2020-09-14"` when `d = "2020-09-14.access"`.

Comment: Thank You for Your answear but in fact I want to select files created 2 days ago and older. If array does not contain any type of file created at this day I want to select first one earlier. In exapmle above there is no 2020-09-12.access file, but earlier file is 2020-09-10.access and this file and any older I want ot push to new array.

Comment: You say, " If array does not contain any type of file created at this day I want to select first one earlier". That's one file. Later you say, "... this file *and any older* I want to push to new array.". I assumed you want the latter. Please explain what my method should return for the two dates I considered.